# ProfileCredentialsProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null

Tags: java, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create **AWSCredentials** object by:

```
AWSCredentials cred =  new ProfileCredentialsProvider("Rafael_Nascimento").getCredentials();
```

The **credentials** file is located at **~/.aws** folder (Linux), it looks like:

```
# Move this credentials file to (~/.aws/credentials)
# after you fill in your access and secret keys in the default profile
# WARNING: To avoid accidental leakage of your credentials,
#          DO NOT keep this file in your source directory.
[default]
aws_access_key_id =  <default_key>
aws_secret_access_key = <default_secret_key>
[Rafael_Nascimento]
aws_secret_access_key = <secret_key_Rafael_Nascimento>
aws_access_key_id = <key_Rafael_Nascimento>
```

When I run the code I get on that line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135)
```

What could be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My application wasn't able to find the credentials file. I solved that by creating the global environment variable (in */etc/environment* file):
**AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE="/home/rafael/.aws/credentials"**

Make sure your application can see the variable:

```
 System.out.println(System.getenv("AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE"));
    //output: /home/rafael/.aws/credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for eventually help someone that lost too time facing this problem using docker.

Just launch `docker run` command with `-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws` flag and it works